# Dark Mode Link Contrast HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a false beginner with HTML, CSS, and Javascript (having done KhanAcademy stuff in the past but also having forgotten most of it). I'm working on trying to get a simple webpage with dark mode going (with as little Javascript as possible). The problem is, the links have low contrast in dark mode. I'm using this code to add a class of .dark-mode to the body element of my html and style it with CSS.

```
Javascript:

function myFunction() {
    var element = document.body;
    element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
 }

CSS:

html, body {
    background-color: ivory;
    color: black;
}

.dark-mode {
  background-color: #142514;
  color: blanchedalmond;
}

button.right {
    float: right;
}

HTML:

<button class="right" onclick="myFunction()">Toggle Dark Mode</button>
```

I tried adding this to CSS, but I realize that the  tag isn't getting class="dark-mode".

```
CSS:

a.dark-mode:link { color: lightskyblue; }
a.dark-mode:visited { color: #6d4b8d; }
a.dark-mode:hover { color: #ffffff; }
a.dark-mode:active { color: #ff4040; text-decoration:none; font-weight:normal; }
```

Could someone please help me figure out a method that is light on Javascript to either add the dark-mode class to the  tag as well as to the body or specify that the  tag should get these attributes when the body has the dark-mode class? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are toggling a `.dark-mode` class on your *`<body/>`* element, but you are writing your CSS selectors as though they themselves would have a `.dark-mode` class.

This selector:

```css
a.dark-mode {}
```

...would target an element that looks like this:

```html
<a href="mysite.com" class="dark-mode">Link</a>
```

Because you want to target all anchors *inside* a `<body/>` with a class of `.dark-mode` you'll want to rewrite your selectors as:

```css
.dark-mode a:link { color: lightskyblue; }
.dark-mode a:visited { color: #6d4b8d; }
.dark-mode a:hover { color: #ffffff; }
.dark-mode a:active { color: #ff4040; text-decoration:none; font-weight:normal; }
```

...which matches all anchors inside an element with class `.dark-mode`.

Comment: Thank you! I had figured out a workaround, after having tried to solve this problem since yesterday, just after I posted the problem, but your solution is better. I figured out that I could do body.dark-mode a:link, etc. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Glad this helped-- happy coding!